# Multiple Drop-Down Menus Based on Selected Value of First Drop-Down

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have been searching for similar questions but they are a little different to what I am looking for.

Basically, this is what I am aiming to implement:

Have a first drop-down list filled with values, e.g. :

```
<form>
<select id="tags" name="tags">
<option value="agent" selected="selected">agent</option>
<option value="extension">extension</option>
<option value="fileversion" >fileversion</option>
<option value="pages">pages</option>
</select>
```

Then, in a second drop-down list, show options dependant on what was selected, for example, if agent is selected, the operators would be `=` or `!=` since it is text. For fileversion there would be 4 operands, `=`, `!=`, `>` and `<`.

Lastly, there would be a third drop-down with values also dependant on the initially selected option.

For example, when agent is selected, the options would be `pdf`, `word`, `excel`, `ppt` etc. and others it would just be a `text box` to type in rather than exhaust all possible values.

In the end this will be used to search a database but it is a big db and the searches are too slow so I'm thinking the values for the options will be stored in an array rather than pulled directly.

As you can see, it's fairly tricky :/ any help at all is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Martin

EDIT:

Found  the answer for those who happen to be looking for the same answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="tags" name="tags">
<option value="tags" selected="selected">tags</option>
<option value="agent">agent</option>
<option value="extension">extension</option>
</select>

<select name="operands">
<option>operands</option>
</select>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

dropdown.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$tags = $("select[name='tags']");
$operands = $("select[name='operands']");

$tags.change(function() {

if ($(this).val() == "agent") {
$("select[name='operands'] option").remove();
$("<option>=</option>").appendTo($operands);
$("<option>!=</option>").appendTo($operands);
}

if ($(this).val() == "extension") 
{
$("select[name='operands'] option").remove();
$("<option>.pdf</option>").appendTo($operands);
$("<option>.doc</option>").appendTo($operands);
}

if ($(this).val() == "tags") 
{
$("select[name='operands'] option").remove();
$("<option>operands</option>").appendTo($operands);
}

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, a data object filled with the corresponding data..

```
var data = {
  agent: [
    ["=", "!="], //values that are shown in 1st dropdown when agent is selected
    ["a", "b"] //values that are shown in 2nd dropdown when agent is selected
  ]
  extension: [
    ["pdf", "doc"], //values that are shown in 1st dropdown when extension is selected
    ["c", "d"] //values that are shown in 2nd dropdown when extension is selected
  ]
}
```

and for the HTML

```
<select id="tags" name="tags">
  <option value="agent" selected="selected">agent</option>
  <option value="extension">extension</option>
  <option value="fileversion" >fileversion</option>
  <option value="pages">pages</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2">
</select>

<select id="dropdown3" name="dropdown3">
</select>
```

Now listen for changes on the tags dropdown and get the options from the data object (example using jquery)

```
$("#tags").change(function() {
  setDropDown1(data[$(this).val()][0]);
  setDropDown2(data[$(this).val()][1]);
});
```

pass the data to a function like this to create the dropdown options

```
function setDropDown1(data) {
  $("#dropdown1").html(""); //clear options
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the dropdowns don't seem to populate when a value is selected.

NB. I did change `dropdown2` and `dropdown3` in the html to `operators` and `values` and the same values in your JS didn't quite match - probably a typo but I changed `setDropDown1` and `setDropDown2` to `setOperators` and `setValues` and similarly in the functions, `setOperators`, `#operators` etc.

Comment: Could you put the code somewhere so i can see? jsfiddle.net? I didn't test it, but it's supposed to work like this.

Comment: Hi, reverted to the code you posted with minor tweaks:
http://jsfiddle.net/ydPfH/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectionObject = {
agent = ["=","!="],
fileversion = ["=","!=",">","<"],
...
}

$('form select#tags').click(function(){
comboBoxSelection = $(this).val();
secondDropDownvalues = selectionObject[comboBoxSelection];
....
});
```

In pseudo code should be something like that

Comment: thanks but your pseudo code doesn't explain how to use the additional drop downs.